# flattening exterior concrete landing

Tags: concrete, tiling

I'd like to tile my exterior concrete covered entryway landing. It's about 8'x 10'. The sides are level, but there's sort of a trough up the middle, worst case about 1/4" from flat. There is about 1/8" slope per foot too, for water. The concrete is over 50 years old and there are no cracks, so it's extremely stable.

Is there someway that I could screed material over the middle into the "trough" to make this flat? If there was no slope, I would use a self-leveling mix, but that's not the case. I've thought about grinding down the sides, but it's a bit messy and seems labor intensive.

I'm considering using tile that is about 15" to 18" square.

Any suggestions appreciated! thx

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can screed material over the middle.  I think that your question is the answer.  That's what I'd do.  Thin set will work, you could even do it at the same time as you are laying the tile.

Just a word of caution here, make sure you aren't using really smooth tiles that could become a hazard when they get wet since its outside.

Comment: I want to use a material that's rated for this. I was under the impression that thinset has a limit to how thick it can be. I will check with a manufacturer and get their take on it. Thanks for mentioning the slip resistance - I'm paying attention to that! thx

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if the worst spots on your concrete are only about 1/4" low, I would just use your grout to level your tile. If they are high... idk I guess you could grind them down with a side grinder and a masonry wheel. That's the best I got. Good luck!